# How to delete card details from Authorize.net yii2

Tags: php, yii2, authorize.net

When I tried to delete card detail from **Authorize.net** am getting error as
    "**The specified customer profile is associated with an active or suspended subscription and cannot be deleted. geeting this error while deleting card details**"
This error occur randomly, sometimes it gets deleted , sometimes shows the above error. It might be a session clear problem , how may handle it?? If someone answers will be appreciated.

Thnx Sally,

Comment: You should check if the customer profiles are indeed associated to an active or suspended subscription.  If so, you can't remove the profile until you cancel the subscription.

Comment: I am cancelling the subscription with the card details, but the error occurs sometimes like fourth or second time while deleting. I suspect cause of this is session was not get cleared. I wants to clear it, how to do it?